# How to show angles in Blochsphere?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When using the blochsphere package, how can I include ϕ and  angles?

I want something similar to this:

[image: Bloch sphere with angles]

What I have already tried is this:

```
\begin{blochsphere}[radius=3cm,tilt=15,rotation=-10,opacity=0.2,color=lightgray]
    \drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}
    \drawAxis[scale=1.2]{0}{0}
    \drawAxis[scale=1.8]{90}{90}
    \drawAxis[scale=1.4]{90}{0}    
    \labelLatLon{up}{90}{0};
    \labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90};
    \node[above,{shift=(0,0.2,0)}] at (up) {{$\ket{0}$ }};
    \node[below,{shift=(0,-0.2,0)}] at (down) {{$\ket{1}$}};
    \drawStatePolar[statecolor=red]{vector}{30}{45} 
    \node[right,color=red] at (vector) {$\ket{\psi}$};
\end{blochsphere}
```

Which produces this diagram (note that the desired ϕ and  angles are missing):

[image]

Comment: In the tikz 3D galery there are several examples of this kind of drawing, maybe you can use then as reference :   https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/

Comment: @Jes: Yes, I found some examples on how to do it with tikz, but I was hoping to be able to do it with only the blochsphere package itself.